# Connect to OpenLDAP with Mac OS X Workgroup Manager?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, openldap

I would like to be able to manage my openldap server using the mac os x workgroup manager.

How do I authenticate as it asks for a username and password as opposed to DN?

I believe it has something to do with the Mac OS X "Password Server" but from what I can tell this is not proprietary but instead a collection of authentication tools put together to create a simpler authentication workflow. Does anyone know the specifics of how to setup?

I'm working  in a mixed environment… Mac OS X, Ubuntu, Centos, RHEL, Fedora. no Windows for now.

Thanks!

Comment: You need the proper attributes and object classes in OD before WGM will connect to it. You can even connect it to Active Directory if you extend the schema.

http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2009/04/building-your-own-opendirectory-server-on-linux/